# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java

I created jar file for my application. It launches perfect, but when I request a function from it (that will read a file in its main directory), it keep showing this error :
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/core/FastVector

I can run my application from Eclipse and it works, but I cannot make it work from jar file.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the `weka.jar` is missing in your classpath at runtime.

Comment: It seems like I have it:  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/ermira/Downloads/weka-3-6-10/weka.jar"/>

Comment: Yes in eclipse. But if you run it from jar you do not use the eclipse classpath! Can you add the cmdline you use to run from jar?

Comment: try java -cp /home/ermira/Downloads/weka-3-6-10/weka.jar -jar myjar.jar

Comment: Hi, again the same message

Comment: Can you please look in the jar if you can find the class?

Comment: Is interesting because class is in weka.jar.